# How to pass HTML to JSP tag body

Tags: html, jsp

Ok so i am trying to make a JSP tag (via tagfile). It let's you create tables that come with an "add" button, that lets you adds rows at client side. So basically you pass the HTML for the row to this tag, and it creates a table to contain that row, and also outputs the JS for the dynamic insertion of said row to the table. And you also pass a  row which simply becomes the header of the table.

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions' prefix='fn' %>
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml' prefix='x' %>
<%@ attribute name = "id" required = "true"%>


<jsp:doBody var = "thebody"/>
<x:parse doc='${"<root>"}${thebody}${"</root>"}' var = "xmlBody"/>

<table id = "${id}" class = "datatable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <x:forEach select="$xmlBody/root/th/*" var="data">
                <td><x:out select="$data"/></td>
            </x:forEach>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <x:forEach select="$xmlBody/root/tr/*" var="data">
                <td><x:out select="$data"/></td>
            </x:forEach>
        </tr>
        <c:out value="${heading}"/>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button id="addRowButton" class="BUTTON  btndarkblue " title="Add" onclick="addRowTo${id}()"> Add </button>

<script>
    function addRowTo${id}()
    {
        $('#${id} tr:last').after('<tr><x:forEach select="$xmlBody/root/tr/*" var="data"><td><x:out select="$data"/></td></x:forEach></tr>');
    }
</script>
```

Now, this is working perfectly when the  tags contain simple text. But when i pass some html (directly or via other custom jsp tags), it outputs only the TEXT of those tags, and not the tags themselves. Eg:

```
 <button onclick = "doSomething()">Click here</button>
```

becomes

```
Click Here
```

I believe what it is doing, is that the  tag, when applied to a non-leaf node, outputs only the data at the leaf-nodes down that chain...

So does anybody have a workaround for this? How make it output the nodes as it is?

PS: i tried the c:out as well, but that outputted the html as TEXT ( $lt;tr $gt; ...)

Comment: have you tried <c:out value="${data}" escapeXml="false"/>  ?

Comment: That outputs [td: null]

Comment: i tried <x:out select = "$data" escapeXml="false"/> too it doesn't work...

Comment: Seems like what you're looking for is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188092/pass-xml-document-via-attribute-or-body-to-jsp-custom-tag